# Is it possible to use a loop inside a str.format()?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I'm trying to code a simple console version of a table, which size is a parameter.

I would like to use the `str.format()` method, `for i in range(width)`.

My first idea was something like :

```
print("{:d}".format(for i in range(width)))
```

To get something like :

```
  0   1   2   3 [...] width
```

But this does not seem to work...

Is it possible ?

Thanks

[EDIT] The objective is to set these numbers as the indexes for the table's columns, meaning I have to have them aligned with said columns (thus the formatting issue)

Comment: You mean you want to generate *multiple* formatted strings to print?

Comment: You can produce multiple strings, each formatted, but here you could just print the numbers directly with `print(*range(width))`.

Comment: Otherwise, look at `str.join()` and list comprehensions.

Comment: The thing is I'm trying to print a standard formatted output, so that it is aligned with the table I'm "drawing" underneath. The numbers are the indexes of the columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but maybe you are looking for something like this.

```
"".join("{:2d}".format(i) for i in range(10))
```

This gives

```
' 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'
```